# StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: 'It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s)

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I have such kind of issue these days and google lots of materials and still unable to find the answers, could you help me out on this issue. Thanks a lot.

Error message as below:

> It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). SocketFailure
>   (None, last-recv: 125) on 10.17.221.211:6379/Interactive, Flushed,
>   last: ECHO, origin: ReadFromPipe, outstanding: 7, last-read: 0s ago,
>   last-write: 0s ago, unanswered-write: 0s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state:
>   ConnectedEstablishing, mgr: 9 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never,
>   global: 81s ago, v: 2.0.519.65453

source codes as below:

```
        connectionString = connectionString ?? RedisConnectionString;
        var connect = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString);
```

Hope someone could help me out. Thanks.

I also leave message to github as well. https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1120
Appreciated!!!